# Custom options menu using custom theme and options

Tags: android, android-theme, android-optionsmenu

I want to create custom options menu as below and also want this to be available on all activities.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

So far I am able to add options menu using onCreateOptionsMenu method, and setting its icons.
But have no idea how it can be inflated as shown in images.

After doing some google search found out one  [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way) . If can get more help on implementing custom options menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those are options menus. If they happen to be triggered by pressing a MENU button, then those apps are monitoring `onKeyDown()` for MENU button presses. This also means that their menus will not work on devices that lack such a MENU button.

I strongly encourage you to follow [the Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html). I recommend that you start [integrating an action bar and using action items and the action overflow area](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html), perhaps leveraging [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to support Android 2.x devices.